# Restoring GPG files in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, gnupg

I'm trying to restore my backup from Ubuntu One, but the restored files have the .gpg file extension. I don't now how to extract these files. I now that these are my files, because the total size of the files is almost the same as that of my original files.

How can I export these files to replace my original files?

Answer (score 2):

You can decrypt a gpg file, encrypted with your key, by running one of the following commands in a Terminal.

To decrypt a file to the standard output use the following command. Replace encrypt_example.gpg with the name of the file you wish to decrypt.

```
gpg -d encrypt_example.gpg
```

To output to a new file instead of the standard output use the following command. Replace new_file_example with the name of the file you want to send the output to. Replace encrypt_example.gpg with the name of the encrypted file.

```
gpg -o new_file_example -d encrypt_example.gpg
```

For additional documentation see [The GNU Privacy Handbook](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html).